# Accidentally changed permissions for entire server on Ubuntu: sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /

Tags: linux, ubuntu, server, permissions

I accidentally ran the following command on my Debian 8.0 webserver as root:

`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /`

thinking that it would only change permissions of the directory I am currently in.

Instead it messed with the whole server. Is there any way I can correct this? At the moment I cannot access my website any longer.

Please help!

Edit: What I mainly need to do is get mysql running so I can get my database.

`systemctl status mysql.service` outputs:

```
May 25 22:19:22 vps27276.alfahosting-vps.de mysqld[21178]: 200525 
22:19:22 [ERROR] InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!
May 25 22:19:22 vps27276.alfahosting-vps.de mysqld[21178]: 200525 
22:19:22 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
May 25 22:19:22 vps27276.alfahosting-vps.de mysqld[21178]: 200525 
22:19:22 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
May 25 22:19:22 vps27276.alfahosting-vps.de mysqld[21178]: 200525 
22:19:22 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
May 25 22:19:22 vps27276.alfahosting-vps.de mysqld[21178]: 200525 
22:19:22 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
May 25 22:19:22 vps27276.alfahosting-vps.de mysqld[21178]: 200525 22:19:22 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
May 25 22:19:22 vps27276.alfahosting-vps.de mysqld[21178]: 200525 22:19:22 [ERROR] Aborting
May 25 22:19:22 vps27276.alfahosting-vps.de mysqld[21178]:
May 25 22:19:22 vps27276.alfahosting-vps.de mysqld[21178]: 200525 22:19:22 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: Uh oh!  We've all been there.  I used `chmod -R 777 /` and had to re-install.  I had a colleague who ran `chown -R :group /var` and spent a good 5 hours getting things back to normal.

Comment: Yeah, well. I need to somehow manage to download my mysql database first, so I need mysql to be running. At the moment I get `InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!`

Comment: Taking a peek at mysql right now to see what kind of permissions it needs.  A little tough since I don't see mysql.service in debian 11.

Comment: can you `systemctl cat mysql.service`?  Is there a specific `User=` specified in that service?  You'll need to `chown` whatever is managed by that system user.

Answer (score 0):

First backup everything.  The chance that you'll have to re-install from scratch is high. You may not be able to reboot at this point.  Hopefully this server doesn't have much on it (only used for this web-server).

I would:

```
chown root:root -R /
chown usera:usera -R /home/usera # Do this for each user
chown :staff -R /var/local
chown :mail -R /var/mail
chown man:man /var/cache/man
chown :lp /var/cache/cups
```

Next, for specific applications you'll want to set their permissions.  This includes `www-data:www-data` stuff.